# Suspicious curl request at system boot

Tags: macos, command-line, malware

I booted up my Macbook Air M1(on MacOS 14.2.1) a couple of minutes ago and, while looking at LuLu logs, I noticed this strange Curl request:

- curl -s hxxps|://support-sp[.]apple[.]com/sp/
  product?cc=XXXX

I slightly modified the URL to make it not clickable and obscured the last 4 digits.
Apparently I am not the first one to notifce these requests and the last 4 numbers should be associated with my Mac serial number; the site is an official Apple one that gives back informations about your Mac model based on that

Speaking to Apple Support, it is probably not something one of their tool is doing automatically, so that would leave some 3rd party program: the only thing I installed recently is Logitech Options+ and re-enabled automatic updates for AltTab and Google Chrome, but I can’t see this behavior happening to anyone else

I don’t really know how much it counts but a deep scan with the  Kaspersky client for MacOS found nothing

It may just be some badly implemented telemetry but I would like to make sure and to see if someone else is having the same problem

I would like to have an opionion from someone who is more experienced than me on MacOS, plus I was wondering: if I make a full wipe of the system, what are the chances that some malicious program, if present, could create persistance using iCloud Drive/some application backup and reinstall itself? Could this happen on iOS as well?

Thank you in advance to anyone who will spend the time to help!

Comment: Assume this is the same as https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/19bf0o3/strange_curl_request_made_at_system_boot/. The comments there indicate Logitech as a culprit, what exactly is still open and needs an answer here?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply! I am not really sure Logitech is the culprit and, since I could not find any info of this behaviour online, I was interested in seeing if someone had any idea why this is happening/if it could be a sign of compromise (or any other input)

Comment: If you can‘t reproduce it any longer, it will be hard to analyze further.